# Running docker container isn't working

Tags: docker

Creating an image from this container doesn't work. It was working earlier, before I added the from centos part but now when I remove it and try creating a container, container creation doesn't work...but image creation does.

I am not sure how to debug this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python-pip; yum clean all

#RUN pip install jupyter
#RUN pip install nbconvert
#RUN pip install ipython

FROM python:2.7.9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


FROM node:wheezy

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 2001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The repo: https://github.com/hassanshaikley/pubpub-ratchet

Comment: Is that one Dockerfile, or more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM python:2.7.9
```

Was messing with the result. When I removed that it started working. : )